# sql time weighted average

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of times and temperatures taken at those times - there is a row for every time the temperature changed. I want the weighted average of the temperature - if it was 1 degree for an hour, and 2 degrees for 9 hours, the weighted average temperature is 1.9 degrees. I know how to calculate weighted averages, and I know a little about select ... over ... order by ... group by, and I think this is how it can be done, but I just can't see how to get what I want.

Here's some data ... many thanks for any help.

```
create table dbo.Temps (EffectiveDateTime datetime2(7), Temp float)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 13:51:45.2630000', 0.19)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:13:24.1590000', 0.29)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:53:10.2590000', 0.39)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 13:46:27.0650000', 0.49)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:10:50.2670000', 0.59)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:48:10.7570000', 0.69)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:04:42.9650000', 0.79)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:27:59.5590000', 0.89)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:56:38.8550000', 0.99)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:08:11.8580000', 1.09)

insert into dbo.Temps values('2017-04-25 14:33:39.4540000', 1.19)
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking at something like this, assuming your version of SQL Server supports the `LEAD` function:

```
;with cte as
(select *, lead(effectivedatetime) over (order by effectivedatetime) timelead
from dbo.temps)

,processed as
(select *, datediff(mi,effectivedatetime,timelead)/cast(60 as decimal(10,2)) as hrdiff
from cte)

select sum(hrdiff*temp)/sum(hrdiff)
from processed
```

It first uses `LEAD` to get next temperature reading, them gets the time difference in hours and finally calculates a weighted average. Of course, you will need to adjust for precision for the above.

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ca8e/25)

Comment: Thank you, I think this is EXACTLY what I needed :)

Comment: Great! If this solved your problem, do mark it as accepted as per the instructions here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Just in case it is of interest to anyone else, the following includes

Comment: Just in case it is of interest to anyone else, I've added to this to include the result from the start of a requested time slice to the first record, and from the last record to the end of the requested time period (I didn't specify this complexity in my question). It seems it's too long to post in a comment, but if you want it, just ask paul@cssolutions.net.au

Answer (score 0):

You should find the time interval first. You say hours, but I am using minutes in order to be more accurate - you can change this setting other date part:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EffectiveDateTime] ASC) AS [RowID]
          ,*
    FROM Temps
)
SELECT TS.[Temp]
      ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TS.[EffectiveDateTime], TE.[EffectiveDateTime])
FROM DataSource TS
INNER JOIN DataSource TE
    ON TS.[RowID] = TE.[RowID] - 1;
```

This will give you how many minutes the temp as particular degree:

[image]

The final query will be to sum this values SUM(temp * minutes) and divided them to all minutes:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [EffectiveDateTime] ASC) AS [RowID]
          ,*
    FROM Temps
)
SELECT SUM(TS.[Temp] * DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TS.[EffectiveDateTime], TE.[EffectiveDateTime])) / SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TS.[EffectiveDateTime], TE.[EffectiveDateTime]))
FROM DataSource TS
INNER JOIN DataSource TE
    ON TS.[RowID] = TE.[RowID] - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, weighted average of the temperature - if it was 1 degree for an hour, and 2 degrees for 9 hours, the weighted average temperature is 1.9 degrees

This would be (1 x 1 + 2 * 9) /  (1 + 9) = 1.9

It would be better/easier if you have another table have an additional column for duration. I.e another table to do the calculation for the difference in time from the next change in temperature (duration).

Then the sql statement would be something like this.

Assuming your new table name is TempDuration with column name duration and temperature.

```
select sum(TempDuration.temperature * TempDuration.duration) / sum(TempDuration.duration)
from TempDuration
```

- Note: By not have another table need a lot more step to calculate the durations and make the sql more complex.